# ¿Versión de WooCommerce incompatible con MercadoPago?

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, woocommerce

Hola estoy intentando instalar el plugin de mercado pago y tengo un woocommerce versión 3.1.0 , al parecer no es compatible porque me sale este mensaje:

El plugin no ha podido activarse porque ha provocado un error fatal.

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/qualitya/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-mercado-pago-module/mercadopago/sdk/lib/mercadopago.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/qualitya/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-mercado-pago-module/mercadopago-module.php
>   on line 22
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/qualitya/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-mercado-pago-module/mercadopago/sdk/lib/mercadopago.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/qualitya/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-mercado-pago-module/mercadopago-module.php
>   on line 22

Hay alguna solución o debe pasarme a una versión anterior de woocommerce?

Comment: Me paso lo mismo en el local Server . Tuve que desactivar el plugin de mercado pago antes de actualizar woocommerce. Y una vez actualizado lo vuelves a activar . Ojalá te sirva el Consejo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas nose si lograste solucionarlo, hasta donde se, tienes que tener certificado ssl activado en tu pagina, yo utilizo la versión 3.2.0 de woocommerce y es funcional con Woo Mercado Pago Module Oficial 2.2.17, uso el check out basico, por si te sirve, y si utilizas mercadoenvíos tus productos tienen que tener peso y dimensiones, saludos